# Как реализовать UI как в Scratch

Tags: java, android, canvas, kotlin, ui

Сегодня в Google Play наткнулся на интересную программу, конструктор, в котором были реализованы кубики (*не знаю как они называются*) как на картинке.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот мне стало интересно, а как такие вещи реализовывать?

Comment: К визуальным блокам привязаны методы, функции..., в зависимости от координат компилируется исходный код .

Comment: Мне по большой части интересен на данный момент ui. А вот по поводу голики, эт значит без своего компилятора не обойтись? Я думал с помощью условий генерировать код или же, задать конкретный сценарий сцены.

Comment: честно говоря я ни строчки не вижу на этой картинке) расширение нулевое

Comment: @ГеоргийЧеботарев Это похоже на пазл, сложив его, вы получаете генерируемый код.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Концепция.
Каждое действие (цикл, условие, арифметика) - это отдельный класс, унаследованный от родительского класса **ParentAction**. У каждого класса есть своя реализация. Для каждого блока - у вас переопределен метод исполнения. Параметры передаются в конструктор класса.

```
abstrast class ParentAction() {
    abstract fun execute(child: ParentAction)
}
```

Разберем простой пример: вывести в цикле 5 раз некоторую строчку. В UI части - пользователь собирает два блока, один вложенный в другой. Проходя его дерево блоков изнутри-наружу, мы собираем верную цепочку, последовательность исполнения блоков. В данном примере класс Printf - минимальное действие. Им нельзя ничего обернуть. Смотрите классы ниже:

```
сlass Foreach(private val count: Int, child: ParentAction): ParentAction {
        override fun execute() {
             for(i : 0..count) {
                 child.execute()
             }
        }
}
```

Класс **Printf**:

```
сlass Printf(private val str: String): ParentAction {
        override fun execute() {
            print(str)
        }
}
```

Тогда, при обратном прохождении дерева пользователя, мы получаем:

1. Генерируем объект класса Printf с указанными пользователем параметрами
2. Генерируем объект класса Foreach и передаем ему на вход класс Printf, дабы тот, запускал его внутри себя.
3. Запускаем метод execute у класса Foreach.

Все. Шарманка закрутилась. Для реализации математики, вам придется организовать работу с "памятью", дабы разные классы могли последовательно читать из общего источника. В итоге, у вас получается простой компилятор, "надстройка". Конечно, все зависит от вашей задачи. Если вы хотите создать программу для обучения детей основам программирования, то данная реализация уместна. Если же вы хотите разработать графический язык программирования, то вам следует углубиться в разработку собственного компилятора, т.к. данная надстройка не будет отличать высокой эффективностью. Удачи!

Comment: Спасибо, а вы не знаете как создаются эти самые кубики? Они рисуются в canvas? или это обычные компоненты, как button в Android Studio?

Comment: скорее всего это нарисовано канвасом. Стандартными элементами android можно лишь начерно отобразить. Для полноты картины придется рисовать самому)

Comment: Ок, буду отталкиваться от ваших идей. А за компилятор отдельное спасибо.